# Siam bibliography: how to cite an interval of papers?

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I modified the siam.bst such that now the order of citations is the order of bibliography appearance, and I have no more line for the same authors.

However, when I cite a bunch of papers I get the list of numbers appearing in the text. I was wondering how should I modify further the .bst file such that I can have [1-7] instead of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not something to be done at the `.bst` level but in citing mechanism in the document.  The [`cite` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/cite?lang=en) provides such compressed lists by default (the `compress` option that can be switched off with `nocompress`) and works with many `.bst` files including `siam.bst`:

[image: Sampl output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}

\cite{article-minimal,whole-journal,whole-set,incollection-full}

\cite{book-minimal}

\bibliographystyle{siam}
\bibliography{xampl}
\end{document}
```